# На сайте открывается только главная страница сайта, на внутренних страницах ошибка 404

Tags: yii2, nginx

На сайте созданный на `yii2` открывается только главная страница сайта, на внутренних страницах ошибка 404. Сайт работает в режиме `Nginx` + `PHP-FPM`. В данном случае для решения данной проблемы я попробовала добавить правила для работы сайта в конфигурационный файл сервера `Nginx`.

В `/etc/nginx/vhosts/user/example.com.conf,` я добавила такие правила:

```
#user 'user' virtual host 'example.com' configuration file
server {
    server_name example.com mail.example.com pop.example.com smtp.example.com www.example.com;
    charset UTF-8;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    index index.php;
    root $root_path;
    set $root_path /var/www/user/data/www/example.com/public_html;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.access.log ;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.error.log notice;
    listen *.*.*.*:80 default_server;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
    }
    location @php {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f ****@******.com";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/user.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location @fallback {
    }
    ssi on;
    return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
    }
    server {
    server_name example.com mail.example.com pop.example.com smtp.example.com www.example.com;
    charset UTF-8;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    index index.php;
    root $root_path;
    set $root_path /var/www/user/data/www/example.com/public_html;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.access.log ;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.error.log notice;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
    }
    location @php {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f *****@*******.com";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/user.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location @fallback {
    }
    ssi on;
    listen *.*.*.*:443 default_server;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/user/example.com_le4.crtca";
    ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/user/example.com_le4.key";
    ssl_ciphers *************************************;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam4096.pem;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
}
```

Вот настройки `urlManager`:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'app\components\LangUrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'rules' => [
            //'<lang:(ru|en)>/<controller:[\w-]+>/<action:[\w-]+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            //'<lang:(ru|en)>/<controller:[\w-]+>' => '<controller>',

            // system
            '/' => 'default',
            'captcha/get' => 'default/captcha',

            'admin' => 'admin/default',
            'admin/<controller:[\w-]+>' => 'admin/<controller>',
            'admin/<controller:[\w-]+>/<action:[\w-]+>' => 'admin/<controller>/<action>',

            // user
            'newuser' => 'user/signup',
            'enter' => 'user/signin',
            'logout' => 'user/signout/index',
            'rescue' => 'user/reminder',
            'room' => 'user/profile/index',
            'settings' => 'user/setting/index',
            'friends' => 'user/friend/index',
            'messages' => 'user/message/index',
            'messages/view/<username:[\w-]+>' => 'user/message/view',
            'page/<username:[\w-]+>' => 'user/page/index',

            // pages
            'info/<name:(about|rules|contacts|manual|levels)>' => 'page',

            // news
            'news' => 'news',
            'news/like' => 'news/like',

            // payment
            'payin' => 'payment/index',
            'payin/<system:\w+>/view' => 'payment/view',
            'payin/<system:\w+>/status' => 'payment/status',
            'payin/<system:\w+>/success' => 'payment/success',
            'payin/<system:\w+>/failed' => 'payment/failed',

            // payout
            'payout' => 'payout/index',
            'payout/system/<system:\w+>' => 'payout/system',
            'payout/view-all' => 'payout/viewall',

            // operations
            'history' => 'user/operation/index',

            // referals
            'partner' => 'user/referal/index',
            'banner' => 'user/referal/banner',
            'partner/view' => 'user/referal/view',
            'in/<inviterUsername:[\w-]+>' => 'invite/index',

            // game
            'game/shop' => 'game/shop/index',
            'game/market' => 'game/market/index',
            'game/bonus' => 'game/bonus/index',
            'game/new-year' => 'game/new-year/index',

            'game/tree' => 'game/tree/index',
            'game/tree/view/<id:\w+>' => 'game/tree/view',

            'square' => 'square/index',
            'feedback' => 'feedback/index',

            'notice' => 'user/notice/index',
            'notice/gen' => 'user/notice/gen',

            'confirm' => 'user/confirm/index',
            'banners/create' => 'banner/create',
            'links/create' => 'link/create',

            'game/stock' => 'game/stock/index',
            'game/stock-market' => 'game/stock-market/index'
        ],
    ],
```

Я с `nginx` столкнулась первый раз. Попросили наладить сайт. Но я не могу понять что ещё можно туда добавить. Может кто-нибудь поможет?

Comment: Доброе утро. На apache2 нормально работает? Настройки urlManager покажите. Как Вы формируете ссылки?

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/start-installation.md#%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-nginx-

Comment: @slo_nik Я добавила в вопрос настройки urlManager

Comment: @slo_nik А эти настройки Apache нужно в корень /etc/apache2/ добавлять?

Comment: @slo_nik у меня произошёл такой сбой с ошибкой 404 на внутренних страницах  после установки сертификата Let’s Encrypt в панели ispManager.. До этого сайт работал хорошо

Comment: А как Вы ссылки формируете?

Comment: @slo_nik Все ссылки сформированы таким образом: <li><a href="<?= Url::to(['/page', 'name' => 'manual']) ?>"><?= \Yii::t('app', 'Инструкция') ?></a></li> Я уже совсем не понимаю что мне делать..

Comment: @slo_nik Я поменяла путь в конфигурационном файле nginx и правила в вопросе. Но сайт так и не работает.

Comment: <a href="<?= Url::to(['/page', 'name' => 'manual'], 'https') ?>">

Comment: @slo_nik Я попробовала прописать https к ссылкам, почистила кэш, но сайт так же открывается с ошибкой

Comment: в живую на сайт посмотреть можно где-то?

Comment: попробуй так https://pastebin.com/4eQXqjzD

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо огромное всем за попытку помочь мне, я решила свою проблему. В конфигурационном файле nginx пропиcаны такие правила:

```
server {
listen               *.*.*.*:80;
listen               *.*.*.*:443 ssl;
server_name  www.legendsoftree.com;
ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/user/example.com_le1.crtca";
ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/user/example.com_le1.key";
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers  ****************************************;
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";

return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

#user 'user' virtual host 'example.com' configuration file
server {
server_name example.com www.example.com;
charset UTF-8;
disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
index index.php;
root $root_path;
set $root_path /var/www/user/data/www/example.com/public_html;
access_log off ;
error_log /dev/null crit;
include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
location / {
    index  index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

 location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    #expires max;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@example.net";
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/user.sock;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on; # Для php-fpm
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
listen *.*.*.*:80 default_server;
return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
}
server {
server_name example.com www.example.com;
charset UTF-8;
disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
index index.php;
root $root_path;
set $root_path /var/www/user/data/www/example.com/public_html;
access_log off ;
error_log /dev/null crit;
include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;

location / {
    index  index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

 location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    #expires max;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@example.net";
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/user.sock;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on; # Для php-fpm
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
listen *.*.*.*:443 default_server;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/user/example.com_le1.crtca";
ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/user/example.com_le1.key";
ssl_ciphers ************************************;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam4096.pem;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
}
```